# Creating new variable using functions

Tags: r

I want to create new variables as follows:

```
MainModFinal$xAdAware_CA_1<-(MainModFinal$AdAware_CA_1/MainModFinal$ParticipantCount)*100
MainModFinal$xAdAware_CB_1<-(MainModFinal$AdAware_CB_1/MainModFinal$ParticipantCount)*100
```

So, I would like to divide the existing variable by the same Participant count and thus create a percentage variable out of it.

Can some one tell me how could it be accomplished as I need to repeat it for several more variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you had a vector of all the variables of interest:

```
vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")
```

Then you could update them all in one shot with:

```
iris[,vars] <- iris[,vars] / iris$Petal.Width * 100
```

Here, `iris` is the name of your data frame (and a convenient example data frame built into R) and `Petal.Width` is the variable you want to normalize by.